# How to express in symbols that a certain point has to lie within the hyperplane defined by vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, $\ldots$, $v_n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I know a hyperplane is defined by $\lbrace x: a^Tx=b \rbrace$ for given $a$ and $b$. During a proof, our professor stated that a certain point has to lie within the hyperplane defined by vectors $v_1, \dots, v_m$.

I am curious. What is the mathematically correct way of writing this down?

I was wondering if it could have to do something with the $span(v_1, \dots, v_n)$, but the $span$ always contains the zero vector, which does not have to be true for the hyperplane.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Hyperplane is an n-1 dimensional subspace.

Comment: You could write the (affine) hyperplane as$$\{ v_0 + v \, | \, v \in \text{Span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)\}  $$
where $v_0$ is some known point. But that's overkill. Some authors will write $v_0 + \text{Span}(v_1, \ldots, v_n)$.

Comment: If $V=\langle v_1,\ldots ,v_{m+1}\rangle$, then your  hyperplane is given by $H=\langle v_1,\ldots ,v_{m}\rangle$ in $V$. But if you mean an "affine " hyperplane, then this is not a subspace. However, it is not clear what you mean. "Defined by $v_1,\ldots ,v_m$" sounds for me like the linear span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to express in symbols...

As you noted, the [linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) (denoted by $\operatorname{span}$) does not do what you want, since it includes the $\boldsymbol 0$ vector, etc. Instead, the hyperplane defined by passing through all of those vectors-treated-as-points is the "[*affine* span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_hull)", sometimes denoted by $\operatorname{aff}$.

A key relationship between $\operatorname{span}$ and $\operatorname{aff}$ is given at that Wikipedia link:

> If $s_0 \in S$ then $\operatorname{aff}(S) - s_0 = \operatorname{span}(S - s_0)$ is a linear subspace of $X$.

---

> What is the mathematically correct way of writing this down?

If your audience is not expected to already be familiar with affine hulls/spans, and especially if they are not familiar with [affine combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_combination), the mathematically correct way or writing this down is to use words to explain what you're doing. e.g. "Let $H$ be the hyperplane defined by the points $v_1,\ldots,v_m$."

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Take the linear mapping $f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R:x\mapsto a^Tx-b$. The kernel is the hyperplane of dimension $n-1$ (since $\dim\Bbb R^n = \dim ker(f) + \dim im(f)$). This is the span you are looking for.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer. How does this relate to the vector $v_i$?

Comment: Span of the kernel.